# using N in select query gives syntax error

Tags: ms-access

```
select * from MyTable where EmpName = N'احمد'
```

i am using this query to retrieve data based on Farsi(Persion) language character, in MS access, but it gives me syntax error.
any help will be my pleasure. THANKS,

Comment: i am not a access guy but changing the encoding to utf-8 or something might help

Comment: Can you paste the exact error here?

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me Access 2007

```
SELECT Table1.Field1
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.Field1)="احمد"));
```

So you don't need the unicode prefix as you would in MS SQL Server.

Comment: Thank you very much, now actualy i want to do some filtering based on "احمد", again no resul, i have tried with N and without the N. This is the two line of code: Me.Filter = "Name=N'احمد'"
Me.FilterOn = True

Comment: I had tried to much to solve this issue and tested without the N, but i got no result, finally at my last try it worked, of course i removed the N. anyway THANKS

Comment: hi guyz once again, actualy i descovered that i am able to search any word in Persion, unless the words which contains the "ی" character, i see it strange. if any body can help i will appreciate.

Comment: @user733922 That character is not a problem in my test database. I suspect there is another issues not related to the search string, but without more information, I can't begin to guess what it might be.

Comment: really appreciate you did comment. But there is no more information do give you, just i wanted to filter based on a field that has Dari (Persion) words, now it works except searching for a word which cantains the character "ی".....word example "یار محمد". THANKS

Comment: @user733922 Is the language set up for your computer Dari? I wonder what would happen if you changed it over to English.

Comment: use it is Dari, and it must be Dari otherwise it wont work for every character, which currently i can search for all Dari characters and just cant search for the words that contains the "ی" character...........this is is strange for me