# MDB Table Column Failed with Unicode?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, unicode

I am making an OleDb.OleDbDataAdaptor object to fill a DataTable object. In the construction of OleDbDataAdaptor, I initialize it like this:

```
Dim adapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, myConnection)
```

where sql is the my query string like this:

```
Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM DBTable TC WHERE TC.Text=N'Criteria'"
```

I am using the preceding capital N because the field "Text" in table "DBTable" is supposed to be in unicode. 
And myConnection represents a connection to one of my mdb files, where the DBTable is defined.

However, when I execute the adaptor.Fill(myDataTable), it fails and throws an exception: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'TC.Text=N'Criteria''. Does anyone know what happened here? I learned that in order to proceed the unicode text, the N is necessary. Another question is, how can I make sure that the field in mdb file is indeed in unicode? Because I can only see that the field Data Type is "Text" and I am using Access 2003, so I can only assume that it is in unicode. In fact I am enabling the unicode compression for the field, and as you can see in the text "Criteria" where is no special characters anyway.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: @Remou Thanks but C# is not what I am using. I am using VB.NET, that's where the Dim comes from. And this part of code is not from a MS Access application, except it is trying to connect to a .mdb DB. But do I get the feeling right that unlike SQL Server, it is not necessary to have a capital N for accessing mdb unicode text? Because it is true that similar code works fine with SQL Server DB, but only fails with Access DB

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040671/using-n-in-select-query-gives-syntax-error

Comment: @Remou Thanks!. I guess the idea is for Access it shouldn't put capital N in front of a string, otherwise it will give the mentioned error. Our program was using the same routine for Access DB and SQL Server DB, and that's why the routine worked for SQL Server doesn't do with Access DB.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Remou response, it turns out that for Access database, the precede capital N is not necessary for unicode text. The N is only needed for SQL Server DB